# Error when trying to export monthly images from Sentinel 2

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, sentinel-2

I have the following code in Google Earth Engine (GEE) to export monthly bands and sctral indices from Sentinel 2:

```
Map.centerObject(table);

/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 10));


for (var y = 2017; y < 2018; y++) {
for (var i = 4; i <= 5; i++) {
var landsat1 = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(i, i, 'month'))
                      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                      .filterBounds(table)
                      .map(maskS2clouds);
                      
var mean1 = landsat1.select('B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A', 'B11', 'B12');
                     
//Create variable for each band
var B2 = mean1.select('B2').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).clip(table);
var B3 = mean1.select('B3').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).clip(table);
var B4 = mean1.select('B4').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).clip(table);
var B5 = mean1.select('B5').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).clip(table);
var B6 = mean1.select('B6').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).clip(table);
var B7 = mean1.select('B7').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).clip(table);
var B8 = mean1.select('B8').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).clip(table);
var B8A = mean1.select('B8A').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).clip(table);
var B11 = mean1.select('B11').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).clip(table);
var B12 = mean1.select('B12').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).clip(table);

var ndvi = B8.subtract(B4).divide(B8.add(B4)).rename('ndvi');
var gndvi = B8.subtract(B3).divide(B8.add(B3)).rename('gndvi');
var ndbi = B12.subtract(B8).divide(B12.add(B8)).rename('ndbi');
var nbi = B4.subtract(B12).divide(B8).rename('nbi');
var nbai = B12.subtract(B11).divide(B3).divide(B12.add(B11).divide(B3)).rename('nbai');
var evi = B8.subtract(B4).divide(B8.add(B4.multiply(6)).subtract(B2.multiply(7.5)).add(1)).multiply(2.5).rename('evi');

//var nbai = mean1.expression('((SWIR2 - SWIR1) / GREEN) / ((SWIR2 + SWIR1) / GREEN)',
//{
  //'SWIR2':B12,
  //'SWIR1':B11,
  //'GREEN':B3
//}).rename('nbai');

//var evi = mean1.expression('2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))',
//{
  //'NIR':B8,
  //'RED':B4,
  //'BLUE':B2
//}).rename('evi');

var bandSpectralList = [B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B8A, ndvi, evi, gndvi, nbi, nbai, ndbi];

var desc = "";

for (var banda = 0; banda < bandSpectralList.length; banda++) {
  
  switch (bandSpectralList[banda]) {
        case B2:
            desc = "blue";
            break;
        case B3:
            desc = "green";
            break;
        case B4:
            desc = "red";
            break;
        case B5:
            desc = "rededge1";
            break;
         case B6:
            desc = "rededge2";
            break;
         case B7:
            desc = "rededge3";
            break;
         case B8:
            desc = "nir";
            break;
        case B8A:
            desc = "rededge4";
            break;
        case B11:
            desc = "swir1";
            break;
        case B12:
            desc = "swir2";
            break;
        case ndvi:
            desc = "ndvi";
            break;
         case evi:
            desc = "evi";
            break;    
        case gndvi:
            desc = "gndvi";
            break;
        case ndbi:
            desc = "ndbi";
            break;
        case nbi:
            desc = "nbi";
            break;
         case nbai:
            desc = "nbai";
            break;
        // Add more cases as needed
        default:
            desc = "wrong_name";
            break;
    }
    
var currentBand = bandSpectralList[banda];

Export.image.toDrive({
image: currentBand,
description: desc.toString() + "_" + y + "_" +  ee.Number(i).format('%02d').getInfo(),
scale: 130, //100 for Band10
maxPixels: 1000000000000,
region: table, 
folder: 'Landsat-8',
crs: 'EPSG:3309'
});
}
}
}
```

When I try to export the images I am getting the following error: `Error: Can't get band number 0. Image has no bands. (Error code: 3)`. [Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7f39cc94e0b622e4345dcc0448873dbc) to the code.

I don't understand why the code isn't working because I created exactly the same code using Landsat 8-9 and the code works perfectly fine. [Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1a5540485269bab1f4dc0077073f2bd3) to the code.

In both cases you just need to import a `shp` and name it table.

Comment: Check if there are available images in the `"COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED"` collection after applying your filters. In some regions of the world, there are almost no Sentinel-2 SR images before 2019.

Comment: Yes you were right. For Los Angeles at least, the available images start from January 1st, 2020.